# Pandas melt and ordered based on another columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

I have a data frame like

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Type': ['Fruits', 'Fruits', 'Fruits', 'Fruits'],
        'Name': ['Mango', 'Mango', 'Mango', 'Mango'],
        'Variety': ['Alphonso', 'Dasheri', 'Langra', 'Raspuri'],
        'April':[120,110,90,60],
        'May':[110,80,50,40],
        'June':[80,110,76,65],
        'July':[85,87,55,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df[['Type','Name','Variety','April','May','June','July']]
```

```
     Type   Name   Variety  April  May  June  July
0  Fruits  Mango  Alphonso    120  110    80    85
1  Fruits  Mango   Dasheri    110   80   110    87
2  Fruits  Mango    Langra     90   50    76    55
3  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri     60   40    65    50
```

When I am doing pandas melt over above dataframe, I am getting like

```
ndf=df.melt(id_vars=['Type','Name','Variety'],var_name="Month",value_name="Price")
```

```
     Type   Name   Variety  Month  Price
0   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso  April    120
1   Fruits  Mango   Dasheri  April    110
2   Fruits  Mango    Langra  April     90
3   Fruits  Mango   Raspuri  April     60
...........
11  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri   June     65
12  Fruits  Mango  Alphonso   July     85
13  Fruits  Mango   Dasheri   July     87
14  Fruits  Mango    Langra   July     55
15  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri   July     50
```

But actually I need the data frame ordered based on "variety" instead of "month". The expected dataframe is like

```
     Type   Name   Variety  Month  Price
0   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso  April    120
1   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso    May    110
2   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso   June     80
3   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso   July     85
4   Fruits  Mango   Dasheri  April    110
5   Fruits  Mango   Dasheri    May     80
.................................
13  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri    May     40
14  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri   June     65
15  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri   July     50
```

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to sort the values in the dataframe by that column such as

```
ndf = ndf.sort_values(by=['Variety'], ascending = False)
```

Answer (score 3):

After you use pd.melt you could sort the dataframe based on the Variety column

```
ndf.sort_values(by=['Variety']).reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
ndf
```

Here's the documentation for the sort_values method
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Result:

|  | Type | Name | Variety | Month | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Fruits | Mango | Alphonso | April | 120 |
| 1 | Fruits | Mango | Alphonso | May | 110 |
| 2 | Fruits | Mango | Alphonso | June | 80 |
| 3 | Fruits | Mango | Alphonso | July | 85 |
| 4 | Fruits | Mango | Dasheri | April | 110 |
| 5 | Fruits | Mango | Dasheri | May | 80 |
| 6 | Fruits | Mango | Dasheri | June | 110 |
| 7 | Fruits | Mango | Dasheri | July | 87 |
| 8 | Fruits | Mango | Langra | April | 90 |
| 9 | Fruits | Mango | Langra | May | 50 |
| 10 | Fruits | Mango | Langra | June | 76 |
| 11 | Fruits | Mango | Langra | July | 55 |
| 12 | Fruits | Mango | Raspuri | April | 60 |
| 13 | Fruits | Mango | Raspuri | May | 40 |
| 14 | Fruits | Mango | Raspuri | June | 65 |
| 15 | Fruits | Mango | Raspuri | July | 50 |

---

Edit 1:
As per mozway's suggestion you don't need to reset the index after, but can instead pass `ignore_index=True` as a parameter to `sort_values()`

```
ndf.sort_values(by=['Variety'], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
ndf
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to `reset_index`, you can directly pass `ignore_index=True` as parameter to `sort_values` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting the columns after `melt`, you could also change the reshaping method.

If you [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) this will directly preserve the original order of rows/columns:

```
out = (df.rename_axis(columns='Month')
         .set_index(['Type','Name','Variety'])
         .stack().reset_index(name='Price')
      )
```

Output:

```
      Type   Name   Variety  Month  Price
0   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso  April    120
1   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso    May    110
2   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso   June     80
3   Fruits  Mango  Alphonso   July     85
4   Fruits  Mango   Dasheri  April    110
5   Fruits  Mango   Dasheri    May     80
6   Fruits  Mango   Dasheri   June    110
7   Fruits  Mango   Dasheri   July     87
8   Fruits  Mango    Langra  April     90
9   Fruits  Mango    Langra    May     50
10  Fruits  Mango    Langra   June     76
11  Fruits  Mango    Langra   July     55
12  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri  April     60
13  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri    May     40
14  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri   June     65
15  Fruits  Mango   Raspuri   July     50
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer), where you pass `True` to the `sort_by_appearance` parameter, and ensure `Variety` is the first column :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index=['Variety','Type','Name'],
    names_to='Month',
    values_to='Price',
    sort_by_appearance=True)
)

     Variety    Type   Name  Month  Price
0   Alphonso  Fruits  Mango  April    120
1   Alphonso  Fruits  Mango    May    110
2   Alphonso  Fruits  Mango   June     80
3   Alphonso  Fruits  Mango   July     85
4    Dasheri  Fruits  Mango  April    110
5    Dasheri  Fruits  Mango    May     80
6    Dasheri  Fruits  Mango   June    110
7    Dasheri  Fruits  Mango   July     87
8     Langra  Fruits  Mango  April     90
9     Langra  Fruits  Mango    May     50
10    Langra  Fruits  Mango   June     76
11    Langra  Fruits  Mango   July     55
12   Raspuri  Fruits  Mango  April     60
13   Raspuri  Fruits  Mango    May     40
14   Raspuri  Fruits  Mango   June     65
15   Raspuri  Fruits  Mango   July     50
```